# How does SAF (storage access framework) recognize your USB-stick?

Tags: android, usb-drive, storage-access-framework

Using Android 6.0.1, API 23,

How do you get a USB-stick connected to your Android-phone being visible in the SAF picker that displays all matching document providers (including your USB-stick) ?? Moreover how to set-up SAF in order to create files and folders on the USB portable-storage ??

From the [SAF-documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html), I tried:

```
public void performFileSearch() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    // in my case, showing only text-files is enough, therefore I guess the type is as follows:
    intent.setType("text/plain");

    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

But the USB portable-storage is not part of the picker's choices...

What am I missing ? Is there an example project that shows the necessary steps ?

@CommonsWare: Here the desired screenshot:

[image]

Comment: "What am I missing ?" -- you are missing screenshots showing what you are seeing in the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` UI. "Is there an example project that shows the necessary steps ?" -- [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Documents/TinyTextEditor) works fine on my Nexus 5X with a USB-OTG drive to create or open files. It uses the same code as what you have.

Comment: Thank you - I will have a look at your project (difficult to clone, tough...). For now, I do not have a working sample project since I am all new to the SAF world in Android. What is most confusing to me is how my App will get access to the USB-drive ?? Does it need a second App that provides the SAF-DocumentProvider or can my App do that as well - and if yes, how exactly ? What I am missing is how my App will recognize any USB-drive connected. What is there exactly needed in terms of permissions and SAF-methods ???

Comment: "What is most confusing to me is how my App will get access to the USB-drive ?" -- you will get a `Uri` back in `onActivityResult()`, which you use with `ContentResolver`, `DocumentFile`, etc. "Does it need a second App that provides the SAF-DocumentProvider or can my App do that as well - and if yes, how exactly ?" -- that is provided by the device. If your device is not doing that, then your device manufacturer or custom ROM developer screwed something up. Again, your code is fine. This is why I suggest that you post screenshots of what you are seeing.

Comment: In terms of needed SAF-"stuff" in order for my App to recognize any USB-stick, I saw "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"-permission. I saw "intent.category.DEFAULT"-intentfilter and I saw a service called ".DocumentStorageService" (not sure why the dot is necessary). Is that all that is required or is there anything else I am missing ??

Comment: In your example, I cannot find "performFileSearch()" to peek how you did it... Where could it be ?

Comment: I repeat, **YOUR CODE IS FINE**. Please take some screenshots of what UI appears when you run the code from your question. Then, edit your question and upload those screenshots.

Comment: Here is a screenshot. The question is the same: Why does the connected USB-stick not appear in the ContentProvider picker list of SAF ?? As you can see on the screenshot, the USB-stick does not appear. My sample-project is identical to the DevBytes-sample code [found here](http://developer.android.com/samples/StorageClient) - except that my code has one tiny change compared to the DevBytes-sample-code and that is: `performFileSearch()`is slightly changed towards what I have mentioned in the original question above (i.e. `intent.setType("text/plain");` instead of `intent.setType("image/*");`

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution to the problem:

Having the SAF-client APP started (as [found here](http://developer.android.com/samples/StorageClient)) - including my tiny change inside `performFileSearch()` (i.e. `intent.setType("text/plain");` instead of what it was in the original DevBytesesample, `intent.setType("image/*");`, the solution is as follows:

If you go into "Settings" (i.e. three vertical dots), you can select: "**Show internal storage**" - and this is it !!

After that connecting any USB-stick shows up as desired in the ContentProvider picker of SAF (see screenshot below) !

...no idea why an exterally connected USB-stick goes through as "internal storage" ??? (if somebody knows an answer to that mystery, I highly appreciate it !)... Anyway, happy to finally see the USB-flash appearing !!

[image]

Comment: Ah, I keep forgetting that this can be toggled, which is why I was seeing it. I hate this aspect of the SAF. In this case, "internal" basically means "filesystems". If you had Google Drive set up, or Dropbox, or various other apps, they would appear in the picker as well, regardless of whether "internal" storage is enabled or disabled. My apologies for forgetting about this.

Comment: No appologies for that, please. You helped my a lot anyway by insisting on screeenshots :) and also with you mentioning that the code is fine. That helped ! Thank you.

Comment: Dropbox would not appear because it does not support SAF yet. You would need to send a `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` intent to make Dropbox appear.