# How to create a SQLite db on a USB stick?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to create SQL db file on USB (otg) device. The problem is that on newer devices I access the USB using SAF so no real file path or handle any more.

All android sqlite openOrCreateDatabase methods need file or path which is not longer possible with SAF/DocumentFile.

The other options I was thinking about using sqlite alternatives but seems Realm doesn't support this either?

Any other ideas?
So I assume sqlite API will soon be updated to support DocumentFile or Uri?

To make it clear app works with large data on an usb stick, app also needs db to store some info on the usb. Of course I can alwasy create on device and latter copy on usb, but if the process stops in the middle data will be lost?

Comment: Try using [https://sqlitebrowser.org/](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)   to create a Db of SQlite and then you have to write a seperate code in a program which will detect USB and will find the Sqlite Db Connecting link. and this link will be then passed to the dbconnection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does SAF (storage access framework) recognize your USB-stick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942598/how-does-saf-storage-access-framework-recognize-your-usb-stick)

Comment: besides, on a Linux system anything that had been mounted has a path.

Comment: @Sayedidrees Sorry what  https://sqlitebrowser.org has to do with the question I asked? Can you please explain?

Comment: @MartinZeitler this is not duplicate I know the file is on USB, and it is not true using SAF there is not file anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can not store SQLite databases using SAF because [SQLite does not support opening databases on (SAF) Uris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57100811), and probably never will for reasons explained in the linked answer.

You need to create the database in an accessible location, perform any read/write operations and then copy the database onto the USB drive. To avoid data loss, don't overwrite the target file (if it exists) and instead use a temporary file and rename that only after the complete operation is successful.

---

If you look at the all [available storage access methods](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped), the only other option is [Context#getExternalFilesDirs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDirs(java.lang.String)) which should not work because...

> The returned paths do not include transient devices, such as USB flash drives connected to handheld devices.

However, for the devices I tested on this does not seem to be true, e.g. you actually can access USB devices using `getExternalFilesDirs()`. E.g. if you have a volume uuid `00A1-CC00` you can access the SAF Uri  `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/00A1-CC00%3A/document/00A1-CC00%3AAndroid%2Fdata%2Fcom.example%2Ffiles` as `/storage/00A1-CC00/Android/data/com.example/files`.

---

If you absolutely need to do database operations without a temporary internal file, you may be able to use an h2 in memory database. This would require a modified [BACKUP TO](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/2b3af7ca2f6001a1eaea5ef49a0d2262e9d1038e/h2/src/main/org/h2/command/dml/BackupCommand.java) statement to allow writing to a SAF OutputStream.